# Completely remove window border padding

Tags: windows-7, display, control-panel, border

How do I completely remove the border padding, or at least make it just one pixel wide?

[image]

I already set the `Border Padding` property to its lowest setting, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Which FF theme is that =P?

Comment: It's not a theme, it's [Firefox 4 Beta](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/beta/). The Gmail tab is small because of the [FaviconizeTab extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/faviconizetab/).

Comment: Firefox 4 now actually has app tabs (just right-click a tab and click "Pin as app tab")... no need for extensions for that. As for your original question: this is as thin as you're going to get when using Aero.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for letting me know about Pinning the tab! The favicon even centers in a nicer way. Regarding your comment about the window border width, if you post it as a question, I can mark it as such.

Comment: That's the smallest you can make the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer this time: this is as thin as you're going to get when using Aero.